# Liquibase generated query consumes all TEMP space, resulted oracle thrown an error with extending TEMP tablespace

Tags: oracle, liquibase

While spring boot runs the liquibase, it does execute the below query and results "Unable to extend by 128 in tablespace TEMP". Since our database has 200+ schemas, the all * views consumes lot of TEMP memory and throws error.

```
SELECT  NULL AS TABLE_CAT, atc.OWNER AS TABLE_SCHEMA, atc.OWNER, atc.TABLE_NAME, atc.COLUMN_NAME, NULLABLE, ac.VALIDATED as VALIDATED, ac.SEARCH_CONDITION, ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM **ALL_TAB_COLS** atc JOIN **all_cons_columns** acc ON atc.OWNER = acc.OWNER AND atc.TABLE_NAME = acc.TABLE_NAME AND atc.COLUMN_NAME = acc.COLUMN_NAME JOIN all_constraints ac ON atc.OWNER = ac.OWNER AND atc.TABLE_NAME = ac.TABLE_NAME AND acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME  WHERE atc.OWNER='XXXX' AND atc.hidden_column='NO' AND ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='C'  and ac.search_condition is not null  AND atc.TABLE_NAME='DATABASECHANGELOG';
```

Why liquibase checking all * views in the database instead of the specific schema? is there a solution which fixes this issue?

Comment: That query is actually generated by the Oracle JDBC driver (when calling `DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()`) it's not generated by Liquibase directly.

Comment: then make the tablespace bigger?

Comment: So should it only tries to get the metadata for the schema configured with data source. correct? While working with DBA, came to know it is trying to checking all *.views, and if database consists of 200+ schemas, no surprise why we get this issue.

Comment: Increasing the tablespace size does not solve this issue, originally was MBs and after we encounter this issue increased it to GBs, but the issue still persists when we add more schemas to the database.